# gwt listbox execute my handler

Tags: java, gwt, listbox

I have a listbox with a changeHandler attached to it.
In this changehandler, there are some very important verifications that I dont want to copy, to keep my code clean.

```
 this.myListBox.addChangeHandler(this.myChangeHandler);

 private ChangeHandler myChangeHandler = new ChangeHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
       If (a<0)...
    }
 }
```

I used to have a `ChangeListener` with `onChange(Widget sender)` but it is now deprecated.
With the listener I had it was easy to execute the ChangeListener with:

```
this.myChangeListener.onChange(this.myListBox);
```

How can I execute the `onChange(ChangeEvent event)` of my new `ChangeHandler`even when the user does not touch the listbox? (to make the verifications happen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ChangeEvent](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ChangeEvent.html) can't be instantiated because is a native event. You can create a class that implements ChangeHandler and put the onChange logic in a public method (validate) that accepts the ListBox as argument. Then from onChange method you call the new validate method. If you want to use it "manually" you can simply call validate.

Comment: You are exacly right, that is what I did and it work perfecly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fire a native event:

```
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createChangeEvent(), myListBox);
```